# Java Changing JLabel Text changes JLabel Position

Tags: java, text, position, jlabel

I have a problem, I have a JLabel inside the content panel which layout is absolute X Y.
The problem is that the text of my JLabel is centered on JLabel, but when I add a few letters to the text, the position of the JLabel is pushed a bit back.

Can't I fix the JLabel position and use it always for the entire application? even if the text changes.. ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: If the text is centred, changing the text will cause the label to want to expand both left and right

Comment: And its not possible to center it, initially, and then when I append characters at end, it stays on the same position that was ?

Comment: Instead of centering the text in the label (seen as you've not supplied sample code, I'm assuming you're using setHorizontalAlignment), try setting the horizontal alignment to JLabel.LEFT instead. If its important to have the label centered after that, you're going to have to assumes greater control over its layout when ever the text is changed

Comment: Yes I am using this setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER), I want to center it at the start, but then adding lyrics to the end of the text I want it to be at same spot

Comment: Then, as I said, since you're using a null layout, take responsibility for the position of the label. Use JLabel.LEFT by default and simply adjust its position as you see fit. The label is currently doing exactly as you have requested

Comment: I have done that, and it actually works, thanks mate ;)
Update that comment as answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: @darkling Verify the answer is correct as you see it, let me know if you think I shod add anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the horizontal alignment is set to `JLabel.CENTER`, the text will want to expand let and right about the center position of the label.

This means that the label is doing exactly what the label was asked to do.

To,over come this, you should use `JLabel.LEFT` as the horizontal alignment and position the label itself as you need within its parent container

Comment: Thanks mate, we already talked at the comments, yep this was the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The label is in the same place. It's position is the upper left corner. With less text in it, it will be smaller.

If you want to use it with absolute layout, set its position and size.